# Is this Apache based API Client Class Thread Safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here is a non Singleton class which is used to send a payload to an API...

```
class MyApiClient {

  String url = "http://www.yankeeService.com"
  int playerId = 99
  String playerFirstName = "Aaron"
  String playerLastName = "Judge"

  public void sendPayload(String content) {

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();

    String jsonPayload = """ "{"id":"$playerId","name":"$playerLastName","dailyReport":"$content"}" """ ;
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonPayload);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(200));
    client.close();

 }

}
```

Would there be any problem if multiple threads were to enter that *sendPayload* method?

I think it would be fine because none of the global variables are modified in any way (they are read only and used to facilitate the API call).

Also the *jsonPayload* is a local variable so each thread would get their own version of it and there would be no chance for one thread to grab the payload content of another right?

Comment: this is actually taken from Groovy code, that is why the JSON payload is created that way, in case anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-threading issues come to play when threads are **using** and **writing** to shared data in an uncontrolled manner.

Meaning:

- when all your threads are **only** invoking the send method, then you do not have a problem - because all threads are reading and using the same data
- but when these threads *change* the content of any of the fields - then all bets are off.

And thing is: your fields have package visibility - this means it is very simple to update them from "outside". An object of MyApiClient would not even *notice* if field content is changed.

Thus:

- first of all, make these fields private to **hide** such details from the outside
- consider making them final as well

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is thread safe. You are trying to post some thing to the remote location. It seems you are not worried about people overwriting the content at the remote location ( if  you are then even thread safe logic will not be your help)

Your logic  "I think it would be fine because none of the global variables are modified in any way (they are read only and used to facilitate the API call)."
 is correct.

For readability and convention purpose I would suggest to use final construct with the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

While there are multiple problems outside the scope of the question with the method you've proposed (what are `"""`, do you really want to be crafting JSON objects by hand, and you don't handle exceptions) your assessment of concurrency appears to be correct.

You may want to ensure that, though, perhaps by making your variables final if they aren't supposed to ever be changed. This way if a future code modification does cause them to be changed, you'll know at compile time that there's a mistake. Or maybe it's not a mistake and those variables need to change... but you'll know you have to revisit your concurrency issue.

Comment: how about declaring the method `synchronized` ? would that do anything on top of declaring vars `final`, which is an approach i do like ?

Comment: also, what is `HttpClients.createDefault()` returns the same object on a subsequent call, which uses cached data from a previous call?

Comment: `synchronized` would add an extra layer of protection, but you haven't made it thread safe - you've only made it single threaded - granted all single threaded things are thread safe, but they don't scale. Why limit yourself to a synchronized block of code when it's already thread safe? And if you're going to use synchronized, don't synchronize on the method, synchronize on a private object. Synchronizing the method causes the object's monitor to be used and can lead to starvation.

Comment: @amphibient And `HttpClients.createDefault()` will create a new instance - that's why it uses create specifically. It is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http-request built on apache http api. Documentation [here](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request/).

```
class MyApiClient {
    private static final HttpRequest<?> HTTP_REQUEST =
            HttpRequestBuilder.createGet("http://www.yankeeService.com")
                    .addContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .build();

    int playerId = 99
    String playerFirstName = "Aaron"
    String playerLastName = "Judge"

    public void sendPayload(String content) {

        String jsonPayload = """ "{"id":"$playerId","name":"$playerLastName","dailyReport":"$content"}" """ ;
        assertThat(HTTP_REQUEST.executeWithBody(jsonPayload).getStatusCode(), equalTo(200));

    }
}
```

HTTP_REQUEST is Thread Safe